# How to display variable value in UILabel (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift2

So I am currently making an application where there is 4 button. If you press the Up button the variable CordX goes up by 1, if you press the Left button CordY will go down by 1, etc.
So I made a UILable to display the cords by using this line

```
 CordLabel.text = CordX + ", " + CordY
```

But it came with the error

> Cannon convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String' Now

I was expecting the UILabel to change from 0, 0 to -> 1, 0 if I press the Up button. But I couldn't because of the error

I am not yet familiar with Swift but when I was using C I display a value of a variable like this

```
printf("%d",num1);
```

The variable in the program was declared with a var and I'm not sure if there is another way to display the variable CordX and CordY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

`CordLabel.text = "\(CordX), \(CordY)"`

In swift, this string formation print the description of any object passed between parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

```
 CordLabel.text = "\(CordX), \(CordY)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

> CordLabel.text = String(format:"%d , %d", CordX as Int, CordY as Int)